# Problem in using \lstinline as description item

Tags: listings, description

I'm writing a user manual with the documentation of some code written in XML. I would like to do this documentation within two nested description environment, highlighting the labels with my XML syntax style, as in the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,%                   
           a4paper,%                   
           twoside,openright,%        
           ]{scrreprt}         
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0.0,0.6,0.0}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\lstdefinelanguage{XML}
{
morestring=[b]",
morestring=[s]{>}{<},
morecomment=[s]{<?}{?>},
morecomment=[s]{<!--}{-->},
moredelim=[l][basicstyle]{>},
morekeywords={xmlns,version,type,value,Value,app,com}
}
\lstdefinestyle{MyXML}
{
    language=XML,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{darkgreen},
    identifierstyle=\color{blue},
    stringstyle=\color{red},    
    commentstyle=\color{gray}\upshape,
    emphstyle=\itshape,
    columns=fullflexible,
    breaklines=true,    
    keepspaces=true,
    showstringspaces=false, 
    frame=single, 
}

% Use lstinline as item in description
\newcommand*{\lstitem}[2][]{
    \setbox0\hbox{\lstinline[#1]|#2|}  
    \item[\usebox0]\leavevmode
}

\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
    \lstitem[style=MyXML]{time} 
    \begin{description}
        \lstitem[style=MyXML,morekeywords={app}]{app}\lipsum{1}
        \lstitem[style=MyXML,morekeywords={com}]{com}\lipsum{2}
    \end{description}
    \lstitem[style=MyXML]{standalone}\lipsum{3}
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

I would like that the first label of the nested description ("app") remains on the same line of the "time" label.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5):

You should not absorb the text for `\lstinline` as an argument too early, because this disrupts the working of the macro that needs to change category codes.

A way out is to patch an internal macro called by `\lstinline` so that it closes the group initiated by `\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup` and then delivers `\item[\usebox0]`.

In the following implementation, the patch to `\lst@InlineM` is local to the implicit group the box is built in, so it won't influence other usages of `\lstinline`.

```
\documentclass[
  11pt,
  a4paper,
  twoside,
  openright,
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor,etoolbox}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0.0,0.6,0.0}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\lstdefinelanguage{XML}{
  morestring=[b]",
  morestring=[s]{>}{<},
  morecomment=[s]{<?}{?>},
  morecomment=[s]{<!--}{-->},
  moredelim=[l][basicstyle]{>},
  morekeywords={xmlns,version,type,value,Value,app,com}
}
\lstdefinestyle{MyXML}{
  language=XML,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\color{darkgreen},
  identifierstyle=\color{blue},
  stringstyle=\color{red},
  commentstyle=\color{gray}\upshape,
  emphstyle=\itshape,
  columns=fullflexible,
  breaklines=true,
  keepspaces=true,
  showstringspaces=false,
  frame=single,
}

% Use lstinline as item in description
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\lstitem}[1][]{%
  \setbox0\hbox\bgroup
    \patchcmd{\lst@InlineM}{\@empty}{\@empty\egroup\item[\usebox0]\leavevmode\ignorespaces}{}{}%
    \lstinline[#1]%
}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}

\lstitem[style=MyXML]|time|
  \begin{description}
  \lstitem[style=MyXML,morekeywords={app}]{app}\lipsum[1]
  \lstitem[style=MyXML,morekeywords={com}]{com}\lipsum[2]
  \end{description}
\lstitem[style=MyXML]{standalone}\lipsum[3]
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: First of all, thanks for the useful suggestion. 
But, what I need is to move the nested description environment one line up, so that the "app" label is placed next to the label "time": do you have any ideas to do that?

Comment: @Davide I'm afraid that deep surgery is necessary in `listings` for this to work. I've come to the conclusion that it's `listings`' fault if removing `\leavevmode` misplaces the description items.

Comment: @Davide `'\lstinline` makes global assignments to some variables; these are not wiped out until the item has been typeset, but unfortunately `\item` does not act immediately and defers it to the start of the next paragraph. This has the side effect that the outer label is misplaced to overprint the inner one